# Why async await operation is still time consuming

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a Winforms application where I am trying to  print a pdf document which has multiple layers on it.
But the problem is, This all operation are running on UI thread and it is hanging the UI(not responding) for long time.
I know, this is happening because of UI thread is blocked so, I have tried to make this operation asynchronous by the help of powerful `async/await` keyword but still my long running method is not being asynchronous. It is not coming forward from the `await` tasks and still opearation is taking the same time as like synchronous operation.

What I tried:

Please see below:

```
/// <summary>
  /// Show Print Dialog
  /// </summary>
  private void ShowPrintDialog()
  {
     // Initialize print dialog
     System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog prtDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

     prtDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
     prtDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;

     _printOptions.PrintQueue = null;
     _printOptions.PrintTicket = null;
   
     Enabled = false;

     // if there is a default printer then set it
     string defaulPrinter = prtDialog.PrintQueue == null ? string.Empty : prtDialog.PrintQueue.FullName;

     // Display the dialog. This returns true if the user selects the Print button.
     if (prtDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
        _printOptions.PrintQueue = prtDialog.PrintQueue;
        _printOptions.PrintTicket = prtDialog.PrintTicket;
        _printOptions.UseDefaultPrinter = (defaulPrinter == prtDialog.PrintQueue.FullName);
     }

     // Re-enable the form
     Enabled = true;
  }





 /// <summary>
  /// Event raised when user clicks Print
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender">Source of the event</param>
  /// <param name="e">Event specific arguments</param>
  private void cmdOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        ShowPrintDialog();

        if (_printOptions.PrintTicket != null)
        {
           //Set search Options
           _print.ExportDataItem = true;
           _print.FileName = SearchTemplateName;

           //shows progress bar form.
           using (frmPrintSearchResultsProgress frmProgress =
                       new frmPrintSearchResultsProgress(_print, this, _printOptions))
           {
              frmProgress.ShowDialog(this);
           }
           if (_print.ExportDataItem && !_print.DataItemExported && !_print.CancelExport)
           {
              MessageBox.Show("No Document printed.");
           }
        }

        //Store selected options for current user
        SaveOptions();

        if (!SkipExport)
           Close();
}



 /// <summary>
  /// Event raised when progress form is shown.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  private async void frmExportSearchResultsProgress_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        Application.DoEvents();

        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        // record export/print job start time
        _startedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        _print.WritingToPdfIndicator = lblWritingPdfFile;

        lblProgress.Text = Properties.Resources.PrintSearchResults;
        await dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(DoDataItemPrint));
     }
}



/// <summary>
  /// Prints the selected data items.
  /// </summary>
  private void DoDataItemPrint()
  {
     // LONG RUNNING OPERATIONS..
     // THIS OPERATION IS BLOCKING THE UI.
  }
```

So, as per mentioned in above code when I opened the `PringDialogForm` then it is opening a Progress Bar form to see the progress of printing the document and from here `frmExportSearchResultsProgress_Shown()` event is fired and inside it, I am calling the `DoDataItemPrint()` method which is time consuming.
So, I tried to make `frmExportSearchResultsProgress_Shown` event as `async/await` but still operation is taking the same time as previous.

Can anyone please suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: All your code runs on the UI thread. There's nothing asynchronous

Comment: Please remove the `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil. It is only in the framework for compatibility with VB6 from 2001. It can cause re-entrancy issues and even lock up your UI. You should remove it immediately.

Answer (score 6):

- your `frmExportSearchResultsProgress_Shown` method starts on the UI thread
- it then dispatches `DoDataItemPrint` to the ... same UI thread
- it schedules a continuation (via `await`) so that when that incomplete thing happens, we get back into `frmExportSearchResultsProgress_Shown`, and since there's probably a sync-context in play here, the sync-context capture (implicit in `await`) would push us to ... the UI thread

As you can see: everything is happening *on the UI thread*.

If you want to not block the UI, you need to *get off the UI thread*. That could be as simple as using `Task.Run` to invoke `DoDataItemPrint`, but without knowing what that code contains, it is impossible to know whether you're using thread-bound controls to do the printing. If you are... it will be hard to get away from that.